# Upgrade from Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 - july 2018

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, 17.10, 17.04

OK it's 21 July 2018 and 17.10 is not supported anymore.
I still have a computer which is running 17.04 though. Now I want to upgrade, and possibily to 18.04. I understood that I need to upgrade to 17.10 first, 
then to 18.04. BUT my update managers says it is unable to do it, I guess because 17.10 is not supported anymore.
What can I do, apart from  a new installation of 18.04 (yes I have /home on a different partition)

Comment: You will need to reinstall. By the way: if you have personal data on /home you can MOUNT it during installation without formatting it. That will keep your files. Do make a backup though; better safe than sorry. If you want to expand the ease of reinstalling: create a new partition, put your personal files there and leave home empty fro personal files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading) and [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0):

First thank you all for your answers.
In the while I had found [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release/91821#91821) and finally this is what I did.

1 First I edited /etc/apt/sources.list commenting out everything and then adding:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful  main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful  main-security restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful  main-updates restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful  main-backports restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful  main-proposed restricted universe multiverse
```

2 sudo apt update

3 sudo apt dist-upgrade

At this point it started downloading and installing and I realized that it was actually upgrading to 17.10 (artful).

4 reboot - At this point I had to fix the booting order of my efi system because somehow now it was looking first for a (nonexisting) windows boot loader-

5 Then, I have ubuntu MATE and I had read somewhere (sorry) yesterday that it was a good idea to reinstall mate-desktop at this point. So I started synaptic and I reinstalled mate-desktop and mate-desktop-common.

6 Reboot - actually reboot, then shutdown: it was late and I went to sleep ( I am on UTC+1 ). And, this morning:

7 First I commented out all "zesty" lines in /etc/apt/sources.list .
Then:

8 sudo apt update

9 sudo apt install update-manager-core

10 sudo do-release-upgrade

Well it worked. Now I am checking my installed software, but everything seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to upgrade 18.04 but chances of misconfigured system would be very high. Best and safest  option would be backup your data and make fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04.